# Powershell (or sts command) for moving SC databases

Tags: powershell, database, site-collection

I have 5 sc in 1 database (Database1). (Databases have been created for each sc). Now the task is to move 4 of the sc database from Database1 and put them into different database (where they belong). Is there any good powershell or STS commands for this?

Thanks
LA

Comment: Which version pf Sharepoint, 2010 or 2007?

Comment: if you are satisfied with an answer, please mark it as answer or upvote answer.

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint 2007 (STSADM - Preferred): 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328(office.12).aspx

For SharePoint 2010 (Powershell Preferred):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell command you are looking for is:

```
Move-SPSite <http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName> -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
```

More information on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx).

The stsadm alternative (or the only option if you are using WSS3 or MOSS) is stsadm -o mergecontentdbs, which is also documented on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825327%28office.12%29.aspx).